# Capybara assert_text not searching on right iframe

Tags: iframe, capybara

```
When(/^I click on the "([^"]*)" xyz link$/) do |xyzName|
    within_frame('xyz-module-iframe') do        
        find('.title',match: :first, :text => xyzName, :wait=> 30).click
        assert_text(xyzName)

        if page.has_css?('.title',match: :first, :text => xyzName, :wait=> 30) then
            find('.title',match: :first, :text => xyzName, :wait=> 30).click
        end 
    end
end
```

I am trying to click an element (title) on a window but it did not the "title" element on the window. Then to determinate the context I used assert_text but it also did not find the text of the element instead of it found another text which exist in applications main window (not the context window)

- OS:Windows 10 pro, version 1709
- Browser: Chrome 65.0.3325.181 (64 bit)
- Ruby Version: 2.4.3-2-x86 (tried also 64 bit)
- Capybara Version:capybara (2.18.0, 2.16.1, 2.7.1)
- Chromedriver Version 2.36

Error:    Unable to find visible css ".title" with text "xyzName" (Capybara::ElementNotFound)

I tried to use page.driver.browser.switch_to.frame('xyz-module-iframe') but it did not worked.
If I put sleep 30 second or more it's working properly.

Do you have any suggestions?

Thanks

Comment: The seem to conflate windows and frames in your question.  Which one is it,  a second window or an iframe in the original window?

Comment: Actually its a second window with different iframe. Thanks for asking

Comment: Then have you told Capybara to change to the second window previously in the test? You need to update your question so we understand what you’re actually doing. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask